# Blender 2.8 Eevee depth of field "geometry clipping" issue

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, depth-of-field

I have a problem with strange depth of field artifacts in Eevee on my Mac Pro (tech specs on the pictures below). It looks like everything is what it should be.  defocused is cliped by the camera (but its not the case of wrong camera parameters). Render is transparent in this areas. Sometimes even if the viewport shows me the proper Depth of Field, the render has still the same issue.

Thanks for any help!

Maciek S.

Screens are from Blender build 2019-02-12.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes in Cycles everything looks ok. I found some workaround using defocus node in post. Enyway the bug is still there.

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that Eevee depth of field has significant limitations. See this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HdTgf4gRXgc

I'm finding this to be a serious impediment to using Eevee.

If you render your scene in Cycles, does the issue go away?

Comment: Please add an excerpt of the video, for the benefit of those with tight bandwidth constraints